# Increase number in ID on click

Tags: jquery, increment

If this has been answered already, please do point me in the right direction, but I'm trying to update the number at the end of an HREF of a link everytime it's clicked.

So, my link, for example is `<a class="next" href="#slideshow-wrapper0">Next</a>` and everytime it's clicked, I want it to update the '0' to '1' and then '2' and so on.

Any ideas? This is what I came up with...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $("next").click(function(){
       $(".work-main-content").append("<div id='portfolio-slideshow'" + (count++) +">");
    });
})
```

Cheers,
R

Comment: There is a contradiction between your code and your requirement, you are appending a div, where is the `href` attribute? Also your selector doesn't select any element, for class selectors you should use `.` => `$('.next')`

Comment: Ah, right. Yes. I need to update the href, not the div.

Comment: so you want to like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JTqS5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', function(){
      var n = this.href.match(/\d+/);
      return '#slideshow-wrapper' + ++n
    })
})
```

Update:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', function(){
      var n = this.href.match(/\d+/);
      if (n > 20) {
          return '#slideshow-wrapper' + ++n 
      } else {
          return '#slideshow-wrapper0'
      }
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rV663/

Comment: +1 for answering the question that was asked, rather than the (wrongly) *implied* question. But may I offer a *slight* (and frankly minimal) amendment, to potentially save a little extra work: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BNv6r/).

Comment: Is there any way it can check the the maximum number to reach on page then reset when it gets to the bottom? The divs with the IDs are generated via a CMS, so are dynamically done based on the content.

Comment: @DavidThomas _rather than the (wrongly) implied question_? Really? Oh, I'm sorry. thank-you for fiddle.

Comment: @Richard You are welcome, Yes, you can use an if statement in `attr` function. If the number equals to a specific one you can reset the number instead of increasing.

Comment: Hmm? The question that others answered seemed to be about incrementing the number of the newly-created element (and the code in the question seemed to support the assumption that that might be the question). My use of the phrase 'wrongly implied question' was not a criticism of any kind to your answer (more a comment to the OP, which I didn't leave to the question, because your own comment there made it unnecessary). I meant only to...acknowledge that you answered the question that was asked; my apologies if I somehow misspoke.

Comment: @DavidThomas _Sorry_ I had misunderstood your comment. _Special_ thanks for clarification and your fiddle.

Comment: No problem; I sometimes overly-complicate my sentences, some. =)

Comment: @DavidThomas .. and I'm not _native_ English-speaker. :) always there is a _bug_ in my sentences.

Answer (score 2):

you are closing the id attribute before adding the count value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $("next").click(function(){
       $(".work-main-content").append("<div id='portfolio-slideshow" + (count++) +"' >");
    });
})
```

Comment: He wants to update the *`href`* of the *link*, not (just) the count variable of the created `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Use an object to keep track of it and increment it.

```
var c = {
   curr : 0,
   incrm: function(){this.curr++}
   }

 $("next").click(function(){
       $(".work-main-content").append("<div id='portfolio-slideshow" + c.curr +"' >");
       //use below to update href or what not
       $("#whatever").attr('href','portfolio-link-number-' + c.curr);
       c.incrm();

    });
```